# Is there a command to execute selenium tests that are not wrapped within a framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a command to run selenium tests without using a framework? e.g. pytest foo_test.py

What would be required on my local machine in order to run the following test? I am confused as this appears the only requirement would be chromedriver but I don't know which command to use in order to execute the actual test.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#h-top-questions')))

driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As you have asked `Is there a command to run selenium tests without using a framework`, the Answer is **`Yes`**.

To answer in simple words, there exists certain frameworks like `pytest`, `unittest`, etc in python to structure your test execution and interpreting the test results. Each of the frameworks have their own strengths. When the code base becomes bulky frameworks helps us to arrange. But using framework is not mandatory.

About your code, I don't see any significant error in your code but working with Selenium 3.x.x you need to download the `chromedriver` from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and save it in your machine. While you initialize the `WebDriver` instance you need to mention the absolute path of the `chromedriver` as below.

Here is your own code with some simple tweaks which works well at my end:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa,executable_path="C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#h-top-questions')))
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand it perfectly. I was also able to run this example locally, it appears that I was just missing the driver path. I am looking into any guides in order to be able to run selenium webdriver tests without the use of a language so that I can better understand all of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

There are actual 2 requirements that you are using. Selenium itself is a requirement, and then the chromedriver as you mentioned. The file is just a python file, so you can run it by doing `python foo_test.py`. There is also the option to use a framework like [Unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html), which can be useful for seeing test results.

Selenium itself is not a "testing framework", it is a library of commands that allow a user to interact with a web browser. Selenium can be used for webscraping or automating tasks as well as testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I want to note that after attempting to execute the file containing the above code I ran into the following issue which i assume is related to chromedriver (do I need to point to chromedriver in the above example?):

'python PageLoadTest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PageLoadTest.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)' there's more I just limited the output for the comment.